# How to make react-native able to receive data from grpc?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, grpc

I want to my app can receive and send data though my server with streaming grpc service. Is there any way to do this? I only find with rest service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `gRPC` support for Node.js there is an official Node.js `gRPC` library. But if you are looking for 'grpc' support on `react-native` then go for `imporable-grpc-web` https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-webbut you need to use custom transport to support the same.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@improbable-eng/grpc-web-react-native-transport